# How can I bind to data being populated in another thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, datatable

I've got a background worker filling a `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue` with `MyClass`.  I then have a `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker` emptying the `ConcurrentQueue` into a `System.Data.DataTable`.  I've made that table public, so that I can bind to it to update a WinForms chart.  However, I've come to realise that the `DataTable` isn't thread safe.

What can I use instead?  I liked `DataTable` because I could add columns simply by adding properties to MyClass, and it was easy to bind to my chart.  Is there a standard solution to this problem that I'm missing?

Edit:
I'm going to be plotting a lot of data (100s of thousands of points), which is why I would like to use binding - for the performance.

Form_main.cs:

```
public Form_main()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // ... add some series data
    chart_highLevel.DataSource = MyClass.dt; // this being populated in a BackgroundWorker in MyClass
}

private void timer_updateGui_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart_highLevel.DataBind(); // Update the databind
}
```

MyClass.cs

```
public DataTable dt = {get; private set;}
private void bw_analyser_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while(true)
    {    
        // ... populate 'values'
        dt.Rows.Add(values); // values are the data to fill the DataTable, dt
    }
}
```

Comment: so are  you having multiple threads accessing the datatable or you are talking about cross thread exceptions??

Comment: I have one thread (BackgroundWorker) filling a DataTable.  Then the UI thread is calling Chart.DataBind() once per second from a Windows.Forms.Timer.  This causes an error because the "Collection was modified"

Comment: can you post your code?? I think you have to use lock to achieve thread syncronization.

Comment: I've posted a slimmed down and readable section of code that should demonstrate the structure...

Comment: @zotty Why do you need backgroundworker? is not enough to use timer and then in every tick you load additional data and add them to datatable and then bind it to chart again?

Comment: the background worker is also doing some of the heavy-lifting of data analysis... I'm guessing you're going to tell me that I should do the analysis in the worker, then just grab the data from the timer.  Meetings for the rest of the day, but I'll try that first thing.

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your question, it's not possible to know precisely what a good answer to the question would be. Obviously you need to synchronize your threads correctly, and you need to make sure to only access UI objects on the UI thread. But there are lots of options within those parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use lock statement to synchronize threads which are accessing same object i.e. data table in your case. Moreover, Data Table has clone which can be used to create new data table before assigning to data source.In this way, DataBind operation will use data table which is will never be modified by background thread. Hence collection is modified issue will be resolved.
Try below changes

```
 private void timer_updateGui_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lock(MyClass.dt)
    {
    chart_highLevel.DataSource = MyClass.dt.Copy();
    }
    chart_highLevel.DataBind(); // Update the databind

}
    public DataTable dt = {get; private set;}
private void bw_analyser_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while(true)
    {    
        // ... populate 'values'
        lock(dt)
        {
        dt.Rows.Add(values); // values are the data to fill the DataTable, dt          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to locking and then cloning, rather than locking then binding?

Comment: @zotty Yes, Cloning will make sure copy of data table is created and used for binding purpose....original data table can be modified on separate thread without affecting the binding process....one disadvantage in doing binding in lock statement itself is it will hold the lock for longer time till the complete binding process is complete...and the backgroud thread has to wait for Data table until lock is released....So the above approach improves performance too...

Comment: just to let you know the .Clone() above should be a .Copy().  Clone just clones the structure of the DataTable, Copy brings the data too.  Other than that, great answer, thanks!

Comment: @zotty Thanks for letting me know that.............and updated same in answer....